# How to center a form with foundation?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

As you can see in the image below, the form is shifted to the left. I would like it to be centered (=middle of screen) within the row. How do I do this correctly with foundation?

[image: center]

```
<section class="section_light">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="four columns">
          <div class="signup-panel">
            <h4 class="welcome">Login</h4>
            <form data-abide method="post" action="connection" id="form_login">
              <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="small-12  columns">
                  <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="small-12 columns ">
                  <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="round button" value="Login"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

I've been playing around with the `html` quite a bit without any success.

---

EDIT: phortx's solution

[image]

Comment: Please provide css too .. or create a fiddle demo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you're working with Foundation 5:

I'm pretty sure, that `<div class="four columns">` won't work.

Try this instead: `<div class="small-4 small-centered columns">`

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. I'll add the result to my question. As you can see, The elements are centered within the form, but the form is not centered within the row.

Comment: @Nerdkowski I must have been working with a different version of Foundation. I switched to 5 and it works. Thanks.

Comment: In my codepen i've used version 5.5. I'm glad i could help.

Comment: I've deleted my codepen. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tudfqr42/) you got the answer in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
<div class="four columns" style="width:100%;text-align:center">
```

Then;

```
<div class="signup-panel" style="text-align:right">
```

And finally for both inputs;

```
<input style="text-align:left"
```

Hope this helps..